# parse_rest module not found on Heroku, but works on localhost

Tags: python, heroku, parse-platform, flask

To access the Parse.com backend, I use their [Python sdk](https://github.com/lullis/parse_rest).  The parse_rest dependency is listed in requirements.txt.  Everything works fine on localhost.  On Heroku, I get this error:

```
2015-01-31T13:34:34.349494+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py runserver`
2015-01-31T13:34:36.767611+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-01-31T13:34:36.767628+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
2015-01-31T13:34:36.767636+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/models.py", line 11, in <module>
2015-01-31T13:34:36.767634+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app.models import User, Role
2015-01-31T13:34:36.767675+00:00 app[web.1]:     from parse_rest.connection import register
2015-01-31T13:34:36.767703+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named parse_rest.connection
2015-01-31T13:34:37.739205+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-01-31T13:34:37.741006+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

How can this problem be fixed?

---

requirements.txt

```
parse_rest
Authomatic==0.0.10
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Assets==0.7
Flask-Bootstrap==3.0.3.1
Flask-Login==0.2.7
Flask-Mail==0.9.0
Flask-Migrate==1.1.0
Flask-Moment==0.2.1
Flask-MongoEngine==0.1.3-dev
Flask-OAuth==0.12
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==1.0
Flask-Script==0.6.6
Flask-Security==1.6.9
Flask-Social==1.6.2
Flask-WTF==0.9.4
GraphLab-Create==1.0
Jinja2==2.7.1
Mako==0.9.1
MarkupSafe==0.18
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.3.0
PyYAML==3.10
SQLAlchemy==0.8.4
Twisted-Core==13.2.0
Twisted-Web==13.2.0
WTForms==1.0.5
Werkzeug==0.9.4
alembic==0.6.2
apiclient==1.0.2
appengine==1.8.0.2
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
blinker==1.3
boto==2.33.0
bottle==0.12.0
chardet==1.0.1
colorama==0.2.5
cssmin==0.1.4
decorator==3.4.0
dirspec==13.10
environment==1.0.0
facebook-sdk==0.3.1
foursquare==20130707
github3.py==0.7.1
google-api-python-client==1.1
gunicorn==0.14.6
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.8
itsdangerous==0.23
joblib==0.7.1
jsmin==2.0.2
librato-metrics==0.4.9
lockfile==0.9.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
mixpanel-py==3.1.1
mock==0.8.0
mongoengine==0.8.7
nose==1.1.2
numpy==1.8.2
oauth==1.0.1
oauth2==1.5.211
oauth2client==1.1
oauthlib==0.6.0
paramiko==1.10.1
parse-rest==0.2.20141004
passlib==1.6.1
pexpect==3.1
poster==0.8.1
prettytable==0.7.2
psycopg2==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pyasn1==0.1.7
pyasn1-modules==0.0.5
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.66
pycurl==7.19.3
pygobject==3.12.0
pymongo==2.6.3
pyparsing==2.0.1
pyserial==2.6
python-apt==0.9.3.5
python-daemon==1.6
python-dateutil==1.5
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
python-gflags==2.0
python-twitter==1.1
pytz==2012c
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.0.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.0
rsa==3.1.4
scikit-learn==0.14.1
scipy==0.13.3
simplejson==3.3.1
six==1.9.0
ssh-import-id==3.21
tornado==3.2.1
uritemplate==0.6
uritemplate.py==0.2.0
urllib3==1.6
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==1.11.4
webassets==0.7
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

---

heroku logs --source heroku --ps api

```
2015-01-31T11:42:12.775108+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T11:49:00.466658+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e17c6b0 by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T11:49:00.466658+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T11:50:02.685571+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T11:57:22.746654+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1045723 by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T11:57:22.746654+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T12:02:22.886402+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T13:27:58.625655+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v12 created by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T13:27:58.625655+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 084c0ed by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T13:29:46.730378+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T13:34:29.324713+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v13 created by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T13:34:29.324713+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 05a0e2c by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
2015-01-31T13:34:40.077161+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by raven.project.mail@gmail.com
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you deploy? If there are errors installing requirements, they usually show up during deploy I think.

Comment: no, deploy ends fine... i have this in the end: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.

Comment: Please add your requirements.txt and maybe the output from `heroku logs --source heroku --ps api`

Comment: AndréLaszlo - just added information

Comment: Try replacing the parse_rest line in your requirements.txt with `-e git+https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy.git`

Comment: You don't include a specific version for `parse_rest`. Are you using the same version locally that gets installed on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing your requirements locally as well, maybe even in a fresh virtualenv:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then you will get the following error:

> Double requirement given: parse-rest==0.2.20141004 (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 68)) (already in parse-rest (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 1)), name='parse-rest')

Removing the extraneous package declaration will probably not be enough though. When I tried installing the rest of the packages in your requirements.txt (which is pretty long by the way) a few packages were not found at all. Bottle version 0.12.0, for example, seems to have been removed completely from the index ([security issues?[]) and 0.12.1 is the closest.

You probably ran `pip freeze` and ended up with a lot of requirements that are not really needed. Here's a workflow that works well for me:

- Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)
- Manage your [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format) carefully.
- Use versions, also for secondary dependencies, otherwise your app might suddenly break or behave inconsistently when a package is updated.
- Also use your virtualenv during development, then you will realize when a package is missing from the requirements file or when a package is deprecated.